# Super Key not working; Can't access Ubuntu dash/launcher via keyboard shortcut

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz, launcher

`Super` (aka the Windows-Logo key) doesn't work as my base Unity Dash/Launcher keyboard shortcut.

Setting it in `ccsm` (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`) by going to ...

`Desktop->Ubuntu Unity Plugin->Launcher->Key to show the Dash, Launcher, and Help Overlay`

... doesn't work. `ccsm` immediately sets-then-unsets it.

As in, if I set the launcher shortcut to, oh, `<Super><Alt>` (or anything else) it works fine, but if I set it to only `<Super>`, it immediately unsets itself after I hit `OK`.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. I think it's a bug in `ccsm`.

I used `dconf` to watch the settings change while using `ccsm`:

```
$ dconf watch /
/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher 
   unset
```

`unset`??

```
$ dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher
$
```

Yep... The key doesn't even exist.

```
$ dconf list /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/
[... show-launcher not in list...]
```

So then I manually set it also using `dconf` (NOTE you have to double- AND single-quote the value string):

```
$ dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher "'<Super>'"

$ dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher
'<Super>'
```

Now everything works. Yay!

**EDIT: For DELL owners: @jooon figured out a different solution. Dell installs a package that [intentionally breaks the super key](http://askubuntu.com/a/752102/300383) called `dell-super-key`.**

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it. However, the root cause for me was because I have a default dell installed ubuntu with the package dell-super-key that disables this dconf setting. See this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/752102/300383

Comment: Oh wow, yeah. I have a Dell too. Why would they do that.......

Comment: not working in ubuntu 22