# Grid snapping breaking workingspaces, how do I fix this?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz, workspaces, xps

I just bought a Dell xps developer edition (Ubuntu 16.04).

When I press `ctrl+alt+up, down, left, right`

It moves the current windows I have open around.  Every so often, it changes workspaces, but pretty rarely.  I don't care anything about having the grid, assuming this is what's breaking the workspaces.  I use workspaces regularly.

I downloaded ccsm, but I can't find anything that's bound to the keybindings I specified.  Also, unchecking the grid functionality seemed to do nothing.

I was able to find [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2329091), that confirms the grid answer, but unbinding the keys from grid dind't work.

The only other thing I've done to make this laptop more tolerable is remote some [ridiculous dell software that seems to have no real purpose](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751661/dell-developer-edition-ubuntu-14-04-super-key-not-working).  I'd love to make a guide on how to make this incredibly expensive laptop that seemed like a great idea, tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer was actually very simple.  There are three steps to solving this issue with the Dell XPS Developer Edition.

Uninstall the dell-super-key software `sudo apt-get remove dell-super-key`

Unbind the `ctrl+super+up,down,left,right` keys through ccsm using the following steps

- `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- run it by typing `ccsm`
- Find the grid section, then key bindings, and remove the keybindings that you need for switching workspaces.

Re-bind the `ctrl+super+up,down,left,right` with the normal Keyboard Utility.

- Open the Keyboard Utility
- In the Shortcuts tab, select Navigation and scroll to the bottom.  Select the `Move to workspace x`, and bind them appropriately.

[image]