# Super key not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, 20.04, activities-overview

I just updated to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and my <kbd>super</kbd> key has lost its main functionality. Previously in Ubuntu 18.04LTS, I was able to click the <kbd>super</kbd> key and the applications drawer would show. Now it doesn't do that. I can still open it by clicking <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> but it's annoying that it doesn't do that.

I restarted my machine and still nothing.

Comment: To me, the `super` key stops working kind of randomly. Similarly, `super`+`tab` starts to ignore the `shift` key. And it seems connected with my keyboard stopping working completely in PhpStorm after pressing `ctrl`+`shift`. All started with Ubuntu 20.04. In most cases, trying to press around or restart an app (PhpStorm in this case) seems to fix the issue.

Comment: I've restarted my pc and nothing happens I can click on the <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> but I don't want to keep doing that the super key by itself should work

Comment: Looks like the authors forgot to write or run regression tests :-(

Comment: For me it was an keyboard issue. I unplugged my usb and put it in a different port. It start working again. It's worth a try ;)

Comment: For anyone with a Dell developer edition laptop, see [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751661/dell-developer-edition-ubuntu-14-04-super-key-not-working/752102?utm_source=pocket_mylist).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be a gnome bug affecting multiple distros. Here's the thread in gitlab

[super no longer opens overview (with dvorak keyboard layout)](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1144)

This all happens under X11. Temporary solution is to change to Wayland if possible or change the most used  keyboard layout to first position.

The developers are aware of the issue and it may be patched soon.

**EDIT**: As of today, Ubuntu 20.04 is upgraded from Gnome 3.36.1 to 3.36.2 and a updated system should no longer have this issue.

1. Just run

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Then run

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

   Now `gnome-shell --version` should show:

   ```
   GNOME Shell 3.36.2
   ```
3. Reboot system to apply changes: run `sudo reboot` or reboot manually.

Comment: I don't think there will be a propper solution until they fix the bug. For now this is the best we can do

Comment: 7 Jun 2020: this fix works for _ru_ layout

Comment: Something other people might try: I just found out that by unplugging my keyboard I fixed this issue. :)

Comment: I did this, but then I discovered that the issue was due to the key being disabled by _FN+Super_ as in the top-rated answer :) OK, thanks for making our OS up to date anyway. By the way, `gnome-shell` is already 3.36.9.

Answer (score 61):

Just in case anyone else is in the same situation as me and stumbles across this, check that your keyboard doesn't have a function button to lock the <kbd>Windows</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd> key.

Mine did on <kbd>F12</kbd> and I accidentally pressed it without knowing what it was. Just pressing it one more time fixed the issue.

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: Why the hell they have a button for this, I'm not sure.

Comment: Exactly! i can't think of a good use for it lol

Comment: mf ... that happend after i cleanned my keyboard, and you save my day

Comment: This was the problem for me too! There's a button on my keyboard to disable the windows / super key. I know on mine because it's a gaming keyboard it's supposed to be used to stop you accidentally opening a menu in the middle of a game :)

Comment: Mine had this too.

Comment: Same here. It was Fn+F2 in my case that disables / enables the **Super** (Windows) key.

Comment: Mine is Super_R + Fn (which are adjacent keys, extremely easy to activate the lock by mistake.)

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts and I couldn't figure out what happened. My kids were playing with the light configurations on the keyboard and accidentally locked it.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman an a scholar

Comment: The home lock button on the Corsair k95 is on the top left. There are 3 bush buttons above the f keys. User, light brightness, then the third, windows lock (padlock).

Comment: @maxpleaner The reason for this button is for gaming. The Super button gets disabled so that if the user accidentally hits it, they would not been taken out of the game.

Comment: This saved me and now I know what the little joystick button on my keyboard is for haha

Comment: Thanks, I thought my keyboard was broken, `FN` + `F8` on **Logitech G512** to toggle the super key

Comment: Fn + F12 enables and disables game mod, and in that mode windows key is inactive. Not sure that this happens in every keyboard...

Comment: This feature (suppress windows key) is used in games to avoid accidentally pressing the key and sending the game to background.

Comment: Thanks. This saved me :D

Comment: I didn't know the FN key existed on my **i-JMB** PC keyboard, but it does! It's located right after the right Alt key, and *FN+Super* does the trick. Now I can access apps and toggle layouts by using *Super+Space* again.

Comment: This - my keyboard has a second Win key on the right with a lock symbol, apparently that locks it.

Comment: You saved my life, i just bought an epomaker and the key wasn't working on linux. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 37):

Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> unblocked the <kbd>Super</kbd> key for me and solved the issue.

*ROG Zephyrus G14, Ubuntu 21.04*

Comment: Had the same problem and solution with an Asus TUF DASH F15

Comment: This was the solution on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: this solution solved my problem, ubuntu 20.04

Comment: wtf is Fn?   d ds

Comment: Does Fn modify the super key into something else?

Comment: Works on an HP Keyboard...

Comment: This saved my day. I don't know why this issue had started, but you solved for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: worked for me on keyboard: cosmic_byte, gnome: 44.1, os: fedora workstation 38

Comment: Thank you for this!  My cat ran on my keyboard and apparently locked the key...

Answer (score 16):

I have the same issue but only when I select languages: Spanish, Italian, Russian.
On English and French it works perfectly (which are in 1st and 4th position).
As a workaround I put the two languages I use the most in 1st and 4th position, and for the rest I use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> , that works in the same way...
Hope the information helps.

Comment: This is exactly what my issue is, I use a keyboard with an American layout on it. I live in the UK and use the `£` key a lot in online messages and so I have to keep switching keyboard layouts just for that. Only if there was an American keyboard layout with the `£` symbol buitl in. That would be great.

Comment: The bug affects also the Keyboard Layout "English  (US, intl., with dead keys)" but not "English (US)". Just as a reminder you can switch between keyboard layouts with <Super>+<Space> combination. Nice dude, you saved my day!

Comment: Upgrading `gnome-shell` to version **3.36.2** fix the issue. Check the [Diego Blanco answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232229/1092116)

Comment: I can confirm. I use English keyboard (super key works), but with Italian, Swedish and German keyboard it doesn't work.

I will try to upgrade to see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: I run update yesterday, but gnome-shell is still version 3.36.1.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a Corsair K95 (or similar keyboard) there is a lock button to disable the Windows/super key.

Comment: Fml... Thank you

Comment: thank you! my cat accidentally pushed it and i spent a day going crazy trying to work out why my super key wasn't working XD

Answer (score 3):

So I managed to find a temporary fix for my problem. See I updated from Ubuntu 18.04, so not sure if this will help anyone updating from like 16.04, 17.04, 19.04 etc. Anyways the reason why I was having trouble with this is the fact that I have 2 keyboard layouts. I use an American and British layout. I am from the UK and always use the <kbd>£</kbd> in everyday use. See, I have to switch layouts to use <kbd>£</kbd> but then I forget to switch back to the original default layout, in this case, the American layout. At which point the <kbd>super</kbd> key stops working. I then try to get it to work for like 30 minutes to then only realise that oh wait I'm on not on the US layout.  So I now use the `English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)`

Comment: Also this bug is relevant with Polish keyboard layout. Switching to En US is only option for now.

Comment: @MaxMałecki How do you switching with a key shortcut  between keyboard layouts?

Comment: @MaxMałecki The default is Super+Space but you can change it under `Settings` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` > `Typing`  .

Comment: Edit: @Atzmon was first ;) 
on the top bar you got switch ;) Or you press [Super] + [Spacebar]

Answer (score 3):

By pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> solved my problem. I'm using Jammy Jellyfish.

Comment: ohhhh god thank you !!!

Answer (score -3):

gnome guys fix this,
just do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to get the fix for the super key to work on sec layout

still didn't fix the launcher shortcut super+/

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me, and may not do anything for a lot of users

Comment: @rodude123 Did you upgrade your GNOME Shell to version 3.36.2?

Comment: I did upgrade it

Comment: This has nothing to do.