# Ubuntu 20.04 Super key does not make windows smaller so I can visualize all of them

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, shortcut-keys

I used to be able to press the `Super` key when I had multiple windows open, so I could visualize them all at the same time and decide which ones to close or move to.

Now the `Super` key doesn't do that sort of thing, it just shows the `Search` box on top and my workspaces on the right, but that's all, see the screenshot below.

I have seen other questions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231863/super-key-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04), but people reported no functionality at all (I have *some* functionality), plus they are over 3 months old and apparently that bug got solved... I never experienced a problem around 3 months ago, only now, and seems slightly different... Anyone got any clue? Thanks.

[image: screen]

Comment: Quite likely, one of the many Gnome Shell extensions you installed is causing this strange behavior. To test, disable all extensions, log out then back in, and enable each one by one until the issue reappears. You will need to disable the erroneous extension.

Comment: Ok it's clearly Workspaces To Dock...