# WIN/SUPER + number doesn't work for apps that are not pinned to the Dock

Tags: gnome, 22.10

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16q5N.png)

Since the document viewer is not pinned, when i click win/super + 3, it should open that, but this does not happen.
However, when i pin it to the Dock, it opens as intended.

How can I achieve the same when an app is not pinned ?
This has worked forever previously, suddenly has stopped working after I installed ubuntu 22.10 on my system.
Already tried solutions [Super key not working in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231863/super-key-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04)
and https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/moq1um/gnome_40_dash_shortcuts_super_number_key_not/
installed dconf editor but upon resetting following the instructions above, it says nothing to reset.

Answer (score 0):

[Image solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4S5H.png)

Turns out I previously had it on

```
settings > ubuntu desktop > dock > show on : All displays
```

Switching to bellow to made it work

```
show on : 1.Built-in display
```

Switching to bellow made it work as well, but only the settings app gave issues. Other than the settings app, all other applications seemed to work as intended

```
show on : Primary display (1)
```

Can anyone explain why this happened?
Why does show dock on any of these options matter when it comes to opening applications on the dock?

Thank you !